# Google Sheets/App-Scripts: How Can I Get My "Planner" I Made in Sheets to Copy Over Tasks I Did Not Complete the Day Before?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Planner Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9jSP.png) Since I take part in running multiple contracts at my job, I've made a planner very specific to what I do in Google Sheets. I've already got App-Scripts running my "Reset" button for each day no problem. What I am *trying* to do is run scripting that is going to carry over any uncompleted tasks from the previous day over onto the next day. I'll include a screenshot of my planner but I haven't gotten super far in the scripting for this particular task, I either don't know to search properly or haven't been able to find something quite this specific that makes sense to someone of my level of experience (not a ton, but I can manage).

I am obviously pretty lost but I swear I am trying! What am I doing wrong? Is there a better script for this? Thank you in advance.

My intention was to carry over uncompleted tasks from the previous day on to the next. Everything I have tried won't even actually run, I've gotten a few different errors on a couple of different things I have tried.
**Script so far:**

```
function copyRowsWithSetValue() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Script Testing");
  let sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Source');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;

  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Target');
  let targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowCount, columnCount);

  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

Comment: I would do your control panel in html

Answer (score 0):

Here goes an untested shot that may help you:

```
function copyRowsWithSetValue() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //Although I made a suggested change, I don't see it being used anywhere else
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Script Testing");
  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  let sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  let rowCount = sourceValues.length;
  let columnCount = sourceValues[0].length;

  let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Target');
  let targetRange = ss.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rowCount, columnCount).setValues(shourceValues); //this will get the destination's last row and place the dataset in the row below, but I'm not sure how this would work with screenshot that you provided.
}
```

Good luck!